# how to update rows with data from another row in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

Lets imagine a table in sqlite like:

| Key1 | key2 | val1 | val2 | ... | val_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| a | b | null | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| a | c | 5 | 2 | 8 | 4 |
| a | d | 3 | 6 | null | 3 |

Is possible to update this tabe in a way that all rows containing in any column a null value will be sustituted with the values from a row with valid data?

Lets say is it possible to copy the row key1=a, key2=a
To every row containing a null value in any column?

Be aware that my table has about 300 columns, so if there is away without explicitly assigning the column  values this would be appriciated.
The only solution which came to my mind was explicitly assigning all values, but there must be a better solution.
I just wannt to copy a row to another location

And if not possible in sqlite pandas python could also be used

Comment: In SQL there is no way to update a column without mentioning its name.

Comment: In pandas, assuming key1/key2 the index and nulls being NaNs: `out = df.fillna(df.loc[('a', 'a')])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

with sqlite3.connect("foo.db") as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql("select * from dummy_table", conn)
    
    # does the rows contain any null ?
    any_null = df.isnull().any(axis=1)

    df.loc[any_null] = df.loc[0].to_numpy() #or use the line below
    # ... = df[df[["Key1", "key2"]].eq("a").all(axis=1)].to_numpy()
    
    df.to_sql("dummy_table", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]